# How to reuse function attribute?

Tags: javascript, function, this

I want to do something like the following:

```
function StatusBox() {
    this.connectionStatus = $("#connectionStatus");
}

StatusBox.nosupport = function(type) {
    StatusBox.connectionStatus.html('<span style="color: red;">' + NO_SUPPORT + '</span>');
};

StatusBox.error = function(type) {
    StatusBox.connectionStatus.html('<span style="color: red;">' + ERROR + '</span>');
};
```

But I get Uncaught `TypeError: Cannot read property 'html' of undefined`

How do I reuse `$("#connectionStatus")` in the child functions?

Comment: Should be `function StatusBox() {StatusBox.connectionStatus = $("#connectionStatus");}`, `this` in a function rarely refers to the function itself. But, though it's possible to use functions like objects, why not to use real objects instead?

Comment: I think the answer depends on how you plan to call the StatusBox functions.  What you probably want is 

```StatusBox.prototype.nosupport = function(type) { this.connectionStatus.html...```

Then call it as :

`new StatusBox().nosupport(type) `

Answer (score 2):

From what I can see the design pattern you're going after is this:

```
function StatusBox() {
    this.connectionStatus = $("#connectionStatus");
}

StatusBox.prototype.nosupport = function(type) {
    this.connectionStatus.html('<span style="color: red;">' + NO_SUPPORT + '</span>');
};

StatusBox.prototype.error = function(type) {
    this.connectionStatus.html('<span style="color: red;">' + ERROR + '</span>');
};

let statusBox = new StatusBox();
statusBox.nosupport();
statusBox.error();
```

But you can also do this:

```
function StatusBox() { }

StatusBox.getConnectionStatus = function() {
    StatusBox.connectionStatus = $("#connectionStatus");
};

StatusBox.nosupport = function(type) {
    StatusBox.connectionStatus.html('<span style="color: red;">' + NO_SUPPORT + '</span>');
};

StatusBox.error = function(type) {
    StatusBox.connectionStatus.html('<span style="color: red;">' + ERROR + '</span>');
};

StatusBox.getConnectionStatus();
StatusBox.nosupport();
StatusBox.error();
```

Which is a little redundant because a simple object will accomplish the same task:

```
const StatusBox = {
   getConnectionStatus: function() {
      StatusBox.connectionStatus = $("#connectionStatus");
   },
   nosupport: function(type) {
      StatusBox.connectionStatus.html('<span style="color: red;">' + NO_SUPPORT + '</span>');
   }
   error: function(type) {
      StatusBox.connectionStatus.html('<span style="color: red;">' + ERROR + '</span>');
   }
};

StatusBox.getConnectionStatus();
StatusBox.nosupport();
StatusBox.error();
```

Answer (score 1):

The value of `this` inside a function is usually defined by the function call. That means that `this` can have different values inside it for each execution of the function. I would not use `this` but rather do something like the following examples:

### Exmaple 1:

```js
function fun() {
    fun.id = 1234;
    console.log('called fun function!');
}

fun.printId = function() {console.log(fun.id);}

fun();
fun.printId();
```

Similar to what you did, if you create the attribute inside the function you should call that function so the assignment will occur and any further use of this attribute, `fun.id` in the example above, will be recognized.

### Example 2:

```js
function fun() {
    console.log('called fun function!');
}

fun.id = 1234;
fun.printId = function() {console.log(fun.id);}

fun.printId();
```

Here you do the assignment of the attribute outside of `fun` so there is no need to call it.